# javascript object delegation

Tags: javascript, object, inheritance, delegates

i'm learning about classes in javascript and i'm running the following code
this is main.js

```
var dog1 = new Dog("a",1);
var dog2 = new Dog("b",2);

dog1.howl();
dog1.howl = function(){
  console.log("test");
};
dog2.howl();

dog1.howl = null;
dog1.howl();
```

this is Dog.js the sub class

```
function Dog (name,legs) {
    Animal.call(this,name);
    this.legs = legs;
}
Dog.prototype = Object.create(Animal.prototype);
//Dog.prototype.constructor = Dog;
Dog.prototype.howl = function(){
    console.log("woef"+ this.name + " :" + this.legs);
};
```

and finally Animal.js which is the super class

```
function Animal(name){
    this.name = name;
}
Animal.prototype.howl = function(){
    console.log("i can only howl"+ this.name);
};
```

the result i'm expecting to get is

```
woefa :1
test
i can only howla
```

but instead i'm getting

```
woefa :1
woefb :2
Main.js:11 Uncaught TypeError: dog1.howl is not a function
```

i'm hoping that by removing the function object delegation will call the howl function in the super class but obviously this isn't happening.
which mistake am i making and what is the solution code to my question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because in `dog1.howl = null;` you just set the howl to `null`, and not delete it, so when you in `dog1.howl();` javascript will try to call `null` as a function, as `null` is not function, it throws that error.

Describe line by line:

```
var dog1 = new Dog("a",1);
var dog2 = new Dog("b",2);

dog1.howl();  // It'll use its prototype's howl, which will howls woefa :1
dog1.howl = function(){
  console.log("test");
};
dog2.howl();  // new howl function defined for dog1 will only affect dog1, so dog2 still howls : woefb :2

dog1.howl = null; // Assign null to howl property.
dog1.howl();      // As null is not function, error is throw.
```

What you should do is

```
// Remove dog1's howl property from itself, so now it'll use the prototypes'howl function.
delete dog1.howl;
```

If you want to make the dog1 howls to `i can only howla`, you have to make the Animal's howl function visible, as the Dog.prototype.howl will be found first, you need to either delete Dog.prototype's howl(which cause all dog now howls as animal) or create a new howl that traverse to the very origin Object that can howl:

```js
function Animal(name){
    this.name = name;
}
Animal.prototype.howl = function(){
    console.log("i can only howl"+ this.name);
};

function Dog (name,legs) {
    Animal.call(this,name);
    this.legs = legs;
}
Dog.prototype = Object.create(Animal.prototype);
//Dog.prototype.constructor = Dog;
Dog.prototype.howl = function(){
    console.log("woef"+ this.name + " :" + this.legs);
};

var dog1 = new Dog("a",1);
var dog2 = new Dog("b",2);

dog1.howl();

console.log('howl before set:', dog1.howl === dog2.howl); // This would be true, as they both reference to their prototype.

dog1.howl = function(){
  console.log("test");
};

// This would always be true, as you have same prototype.
console.log(dog1.__proto__.howl === dog2.__proto__.howl);

// This would be false, as dog1 now use a new assigned one, while dog2 use the prototype one.
console.log('howl after set:', dog1.howl === dog2.howl); 
dog2.howl();
delete dog1.howl;

console.log("howl after delete:", dog1.howl === dog2.howl); // This would be true

// Make all the dogs able to howl like animal..
Dog.prototype.originHowl = function() {
    var current = this;
    var parent = Object.getPrototypeOf(current);
    // Traverse up prototype chain and break until the parents can't howl.
    while(parent.howl && parent.howl instanceof Function) {
        current = parent;
        parent = Object.getPrototypeOf(current);
    }
    current.howl.call(this);
};

dog1.originHowl();
```

Comment: tried it  now it returns  
`woefa :1  
woefb :2  
woefa :1`
so delete doesn't delete the function for some reason

Comment: It deletes the function you set to it from `dog1.howl = function...`

Comment: the dogs actually do share the same howl() function and the reason the "test" isn't logged is because the function in main.js gets added to the dog object instead of somehow changing the prototype howl() function and i dont understand what you mean with the "It deletes the function you set to it from" comment please add a code example

Comment: When you set howl test function to dog1, dog2 won't get that function, so it still howls `woefb :2`, you can only see test if you makes `dog1` howls before `delete dog.howl;`

Comment: console.log(dog1.__proto__.howl === dog2.__proto__.howl);  
this evaluates to true altough i don't know why i have to add the __proto__ thing so the howl functions are the same object and shared across dogs

Comment: I've already added your `console.log(dog1.__proto__.howl === dog2.__proto__.howl);` and added some other `console log` to demonstrate, try to run the snippet.

Comment: i was thinking that deleting(or in my case setting to null) would cause the lookup at dog.howl to fail and delegate to animal.  why doesn't that work?

Comment: Because before that delete, the howl chain is : `dog1.howl => Dog.prototype.howl => Animal.prototype.howl`, and `delete dog1.howl` can only delete the one the belongs to `dog1`, then it deletgate to `Dog.prototype.howl`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83250/discussion-between-paul-boon-and-fuyushimoya).